# grep:argument list too long

Tags: bash, terminal, grep

I need to delete 2 lines above and 4 lines below the lines starting with `'Possible'`. This this line should also be erased. I'm not used to work in the terminal, but seems that for what I want the solution below is the most straightforward.

The problem is that my file has over 70000 lines, and it seems to be too much for `grep`:

```
$ grep -v "$(grep -E -a -B 2 -A 3 'Possible' structure)" structure >final
-bash: /bin/grep: Argument list too long
```

Is there any other way to accomplish this? A snippet of the input file, with a part to be erased:

```
gi|41|gb|JH9|.1(59-594) Length: 73 bp
Type: Glu   Anticodon: CTC at 33-35 (59424-59426)   Score: 22.64
Possible pseudogene:  HMM Sc=43.51  Sec struct Sc=-20.87
         *    |    *    |    *    |    *    |    *    |    *    |    *    |  
Seq: GCCCGTTTGGCTCAGTGGAtAGAGCATCGGCCCTCAgACCGTAGGGtCCTGGGTTCAGTTCTGGTCAAGGGCA
Str: >>>>.>...>>>>........<<<<.>>>>........<<<.<......>.>>.......<<.<..<.<<<<.
```

Comment: @Rubens : thanks! looks more decent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `sed`,

```
sed 'N;/^[^\n]*\n[^\n]*$/N; /.*\n.*\n.*Possible/{$q;N;N;N;d};P;D;' structure > final
```

Comment: if I understood what you wrote, the {$q;N;N;N;d} says the posterior 3 lines to be deleted(N;N;N;d)?? But is counting the line of Possible also, so one line is staying. Nevertheless if I add an N,thee the output is completely different

Comment: @Nelly, Each `N` is adding one line. In this case, It will delete `2 lines + possible line + 3 lines`. I tested and it is working fine even though if add `N`.

Comment: @Nelly, Try this: `sed 'N;/^[^\n]*\n[^\n]*$/N; /.*\n.*\n.*Possible/{$q;N;N;N;N;d};P;D;'` for deleting `2 lines + possible line + 4 lines`.

Comment: yes, I did that before, now it works, although it forms gaps in the file, I am trying to remove the previous o posterior empty line, but having 5Ns change the command completly

Comment: sed 'N;/^[^\n]*\n[^\n]*$/N; /.*\n.*\n.*Possible/{$q;N;N;N;N;N;d};P;D;' structure > final
why this doesn't work? I instead of 4 have 5 Ns

Comment: @Nelly, Is your `structure` file having 5 lines after `Possible`?

Comment: after 'Possible' there are 3 written lines and one empty line, nevertheless {$q;N;N;N;N;d}leaves the empty line, so the output accumulates empty lines in a road.

Comment: @Nelly, I don't know why it is not working for you. For me, It is working. `N` will read next line( It can be empty or whatever) `d` deletes.

Comment: It works with `GNU sed`, but not `FreeBSD sed` (OSX) -- even if you add `;` after `d`, which is needed there. Any idea why?

Answer (score 4):

> The problem is that my file has over 70000 lines, and it seems to be
>   too much for grep:

No, the fact is that `grep -E -a -B 2 -A 3 'Possible' structure` expands into something that causes the argument list to be too large.  You can use process substitution instead:

```
grep -v -f <(grep -E -a -B 2 -A 3 'Possible' structure) structure >final
```

Comment: although seems to work for small files, takes a long time for my real inputfiles

Answer (score 3):

I think that you should split your command into two stages. At first stage you select the strings which you don't wish to see in the output (the inner grep) and save the result into a file. On the second stage you check the input using `-f` grep flag (`-f` allows to specify pattern in a file instead of the command line).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that with `grep`.  I'd suggest doing this in `awk` instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{
  # Record the current line in an array
  line[NR]=$0;
}

# If we saw "Possible" 3 lines ago, remove the last 5 lines from the array
(NR-3) in line && line[NR-3]~/Possible/ {
  for (i=5;i;i--) {
    delete line[NR-i];
  }
}

# Print the last 5th line if it's still in the buffer, then remove it to save memory
(NR-5) in line {
  print line[NR-5];
  delete line[NR-5];
}

# And print anything remaining in the buffer
END {
  for (i=NR-4;i<=NR;i++) {
    if (i in line) {
      print line[i];
    }
  }
}
```

With the "shebang" at the top, you can make this an independent script.  Or you could squish it all onto one command line if you really want.

Because we're running through your input data with a 5-line sliding window, it shouldn't be a problem to handle datasets of any length -- 70000 lines, 7 million lines, whatever.

Comment: +1; Perhaps not a requirement, but you'd need to use `(NR-5) in line` and `if (i in line)` to properly handle _empty_ lines.

Comment: Yup, you're right that I'm not handling blank lines properly. Your suggestion is also important because referring to an array element the way I did actually *causes it to exist*.  Oddly, your suggestion doesn't quite work for me, as `(NR-5) in line` appears to evaluate true even when `NR == 3`.  Still trying to figure out why.

Comment: OH.  Got it.  I also need to change the first condition, as merely testing the regexp against against `line[NR-3]` causes that array element to exist.

Comment: Thanks, and thanks for pointing out the referencing-an-element-is-creating-it issue.